# A clopen one-dimensional set in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, terminology

The set $\{(x,y):y=x^2\}$ seems (to me) a one-dimensional clopen set in $\mathbb R^2$. Formally, the one-dimensional clopen set is a set that is both closed and open considering the topology of $\mathbb R^1$.

However, the name "one-dimensional clopen set" sounds sloppy. Are there better naming (or definition)?

Comment: There are no clopen sets other than  the empty set and $\mathbb R^{2}$ in $\mathbb R^{2}$.

Comment: Both open and closed sets are only empty and the whole set.

Comment: The set is closed, but not open. For example, it doesn't contain an open ball $B_r(0,0)$ around $(0,0)$, for any $r>0$.

Comment: @KentaS Can I "consider the topology of $\mathbb R^1$" in $\mathbb R^2$ space?

Comment: whatever "consider the topology of $\Bbb R^1$" might mean, it's irrelevant here: a clopen subset of $\Bbb R^2$ is a subset that's clopen with respect to the standard topology.

Comment: Note that [$\mathbb{R^2}$ is connected $\iff$ the only clopen sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is itself and the empty set].